# endless pagination with kaminari and jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I am trying to create a nice endless pagination with kaminari and jquery, i have seen a tutorial on this kind of topic but it is done with will_paginate and jquery. This time around i want to be able to do it with kaminari gem. Any help here. Thank

Comment: i checked out this link but i dont no if can help: http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice tutorial here [Create-Infinite-Scrolling-with-jQuery](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-Infinite-Scrolling-with-jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

There is one more Gem [jquery-infinite-pages](https://github.com/magoosh/jquery-infinite-pages) which really works well with Kaminari. The Readme file has a very nice explanation and a demo example as well.

I am sure this gem will save your day. Especially if someone is newbie to Rails.